# wrong week days symbols (weekdaySymbols)

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to change the weeks day symbols in swift
with the code below

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE d MMM"
    dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols = ["Måndag", "Tisdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag", "Lördag", "Söndag"]
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())  
print(dateString)
```

And i am getting this wrong day blow

> Tisdag 9 Jul
>
> but today is Monday

Comment: Just set your locale to Sweeden `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "sv_SE")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of managing weekday names yourself, you could use DateFormatter's template api.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("dEEEEMMM")
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date()).capitalized(with: locale)
print(dateString)
```

This should use the phone's locale, which should be what user wants most times.

But you can also set the locale manually.

If you add

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "sv_SE")
dateFormatter.locale = locale
```

it will print

```
Måndag 9 Juli
```

if you use

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
```

it prints

```
Montag, 9. Juli
```

Answer (score 0):

weekdaySymbols start with sunday, not with monday. You need to change this:

```
dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols = ["Söndag", "Måndag", "Tisdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag", "Lördag"]
```